# Private method returned as string

Tags: jquery, plugins, methods

I'm developing a simple jquery plugin and im having a difficulties setting up the method structure. Could someone please enlighten me. I am using the plugin structure as described in the official Jquery Authoring documentation.

The problem I am having is when calling the private function _generateID, the function actually returns the function text ( function() { return this.. ) instead of 'hi'.

```
(function( $ ){

    var methods = {
        init : function( options ) {
            return this.each(function() {

            });
        },

        _generateID : function() {
            return this.each(function() {
                return 'hi';
            });
        },

        create : function( options ) {
            return this.each(function() {
                var settings = {
                    'id' : methods._generateID,
                };
                if ( options ) { $.extend( settings, options ); }
                $('<div>', {
                    id : settings.id,
                }).appendTo(this);              
            });
        },

        destroy : function( id ) {
            return this.each(function(){
                $(window).unbind('#'+id);
                $('#'+id).remove();
            });
        }
    };

    $.fn.workzone = function( method ) {
        if ( methods[method] ) {
            return methods[method].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
        } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
            return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
        } else {
            $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.workzone' );
        }    
    };

})( jQuery );
```

Answer (score 4):

you must call function with parentheses `methods._generateID()`.

Comment: Thanks. That does actually work. But I also realized an other problem. The function was returning this.each when I needed to simply return my Id. I got it all sorted out now :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

Where did you call the function? I only see:

```
var settings = {
   'id' : methods._generateID,
};
```

Perhaps you meant:

```
var settings = {
   'id' : methods._generateID(),
};
```

Function calls take the form `return_value = function_name(arg_list);`

Comment: BTW it wasn't returning "a string", but somewhere where you were outputting `settings.id`, the output mechanism was visualising the function reference.

Answer (score 0):

From where you are calling. Within the plugin or calling from out side.

Headshota's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5633117/private-method-returned-as-string/5633154#5633154) for calling the method within the plugin.

```
$('div').pluginName('_generateID', arg0, arg1, ...); //Way to call a plugin method from outside out side plugin and pass arguements.
```

Note that, passing method name as first string argument and then other parameters.